# How to trace what's getting run during a login to an X11 session?

Tags: x11, login, startx

I'm trying to debug the fact that my .xinitrc file is not being run, but whenever I need to debug anything having to do with X11 startup I feel it's like "going down the rabbit hole": what's the window manager, what's the session manager, what's the desktop manager, what's the yadda-yadda-yadda...  There seem to be so many variables and so many possible execution paths I quickly get totally lost.

Therefore, I'm hoping to find a way (as generic as possible) to trace what's getting run once I type in my password into a graphical login screen.  By "generic" I mean that it is independent of the window manager, desktop manager, etc., etc., that I'm using.

Comment: Are you logging in in graphical mode (with a display manager) (in which case that's why `.xinitrc` isn't being run!), or are you logging in in text mode and running `startx` or `xinit`? Do you have root access?

Comment: try putting your cmds in `~/.xsession` or failing that `~/.xprofile` and look in `/etc/*/Xsession` for what might be the shell script start of the process.

Comment: @Gilles: I'm logging in in graphical mode.  The aim of the question was to find some way to get my bearings through the maze of X11-related options.  There are too many variables in play, too many possible different configurations to consider.  Your observation explains what I'm getting, but somehow I feel as lost as I was before I read your comment.  I'm looking for some tools to navigate through this mess with.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on your Login Manager whatever .xinitrc or some other *.desktop configuration gets read to execute the session.